# Installing PgRouting

Tags: pgrouting

I am trying to install pgRouting 2.0 on postgressql. After writing the data from the share and lib folder into C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1... I tried to create pgrouting extension on pgadmin PgSQL console by using the command "CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting". But I got the error that the library librouting.dll doesn't exist. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you follow http://anitagraser.com/2013/07/06/pgrouting-2-0-for-windows-quick-guide/? Where did you get pgRouting for Postgres 9.1 from?

Comment: Yes, I followed exactly your description there:  http://anitagraser.com/2013/07/06/pgrouting-2-0-for-windows-quick-guide/.  pgRouting was downloading from http://winnie.postgis.net/download/windows/pg91/buildbot/.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to install an extension with `CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting` you must have all the files from pgrouting installed in the right directories. From your error message, it means that you probably have the `....\PostgreSQL...\share\extension\pgrouting.control` in the right place, but you don't have the `librouting.dll` in the right folder:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1...\lib\librouting.dll`

If the dll is there, it means that the user running PostgreSQL doesn't have the rights to read and execute the dll.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Everything is at the right place. How to grant the user the rights to run .dll?

Comment: Did you get the right binaries (32bits or 64bits) for the right version of PostgreSQL (9.2)? If you install postgresql with the same user as pgrouting, it should be alright. Note that you need a pgrouting which is the same version as postgresql (32/64bits and 9.2).

Comment: I got the binaries for PostgreSQL 9.1. Is it not working with PG 9.1 or what?

Comment: It will work with  9.1 as long as both were compiled in 64bits (or both 32bits)